# Cannot drag and drop files from the Dock folders

Tags: dock, ui

On the Dock I have two folders, Documents and Downloads.

I was used to drag files from the Downloads folder and drop them on the Desktop or somewhere else.

Now I can't do it anymore. I'm only able to drag and drop files from the Dock folder to the Trash.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaunching the finder fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Trackpad" and turn off "Force Click and haptic feedback".  This worked for me..