# macOS Monterey -- Possible to enable drag-and-drop from dock "list" style folders?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, ui

I'm running macOS Monterey (12.0.1) on a recently-purchased M1 Pro.  For folders on the dock, if set to "List" style, I cannot drag-and-drop.  If set to "Grid" style, this is no problem.  I do not recall this being an issue on prior macOS versions, but most recently had my folders set to Grid.  Of course, I can click "Open in Finder" and then drag (even when Finder is in list mode!)

[image: Cannot drag-and-drop from dock folder with "List" style]

I see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72543/cannot-drag-and-drop-files-from-the-dock-folders) question but it seems to be a problem with drag-and-drop wholesale, not just for List style.  (Also, rebooting did not solve the issue.)

Comment: I have the same question, really surprised this doesn't seem to be covered anywhere